# Exception on uploading big file by FTP

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I'm making a FTP client and trying to upload file to server (~300 MB), but I get following error when nearly 100 MB of the file were transfered:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

Here's my code:

```
private void UploadFile(string filepath, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://" + server + "/" + filename);

            //ftp.KeepAlive = false;
            //ftp.Timeout = 1000000;
            //ftp.UsePassive = true;
            //ftp.ReadWriteTimeout = 100000;

            Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;


            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filepath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.Close();


            Stream requestStream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
            //requestStream.ReadTimeout = 1000000;
            //requestStream.WriteTimeout = 1000000;
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            requestStream.Close();         

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { CreateRunLogFile(ex.Message); }

        CreateRunLogFile("Uploading of file " + filepath + " ended.");
    }
```

I try to use,

```
ftp.KeepAlive = false;
ftp.Timeout = 1000000;
ftp.UsePassive = true;
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: Is the file still transferring? This could be a timeout of the control channel, where nothing is actually wrong. Additionally, have you tried to upload the identical file with an ftp client, such as FileZilla? What behavior do you see?

Comment: @JamieMeyer, No, when program throw exeption file transferring ends.About control channel, I don't understand.I've tried to upload with FileZilla and WinSCP, file loaded successfully. And one more, i've noticed, that exeption thrown, after 100 sec of uploading.

Comment: The timeout value which you have established is in milliseconds, which likely explains what is going on. Also, it appears that this is also the default, contrary to the documented default. Try setting it to -1 and try again. This may help: http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2012/04/06/damn-the-documentation-ftpwebrequest-timeout-default-value-is-not-infinite/

Comment: @JamieMeyer, I changed code to this: `FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + server + "/" + filename);
ftp.UsePassive = true;
Path.GetFileName(filepath);
ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
ftp.Timeout = -1;` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the destination firewall settings.  If it is a LINUX server running vsFTPd then the server ftp service has FILESIZE and TIMEOUT settings in the config file.

Be sure to restart vsFTPd service after FILESIZE and TIMEOUT settings are adjusted.